# Paypal payment for mobile web view

Tags: mobile, paypal

I have my android app and all paypal payment are being done from web view within my mobile app.

The problem is that the screens are not suitable for mobile view like payment and cancel subscription.

Does paypal have a web view mobile compatible screens?

Ziv

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your integration, I think what you are looking for is [Express Checkout on Mobile Devices](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices/) this should give you a more mobile friendly payment page.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that the cancel subscription page is not mobile friendly. Do you know if there is a chance to have this page as mobile friendly?